# C++ Vector Accessor Method

Tags: c++, vector

I'm playing around with Vectors, trying to better my knowledge of them.
I created (i think) an empty vector: `vector<string> contents;`
I created (i think) an accessor method: `vector<string> getContents();`
The method looks like this:

```
    vector<string> Album::getContents()
    {
        cout << "\nAlbum Contents:\n\n" << endl;
        for(vector<string>::iterator iter = contents.begin(); 
                                     iter !=contents.end(); iter++)
           {
               cout << *iter << endl;
           }
    }
```

Is this a suitable accessor method or am I over thinking something? Because my `getContents` doesn't return anything but prints it instead...

Assuming this is a valid method, what would be a better way to return the contents of a vector collection? Thanks.

Edit: I've just compiled it and my method needs to return something... So now im assuming my method is pointless and you should be able to return the vectors collection item by item similar to a Java array using a for-loop? I dunno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost suitable. But your method needs to return something. It is defined to return a copy of a vector, so it could work by returning a copy of `contents`:

```
vector<string> Album::getContents()
{
    cout << "\nAlbum Contents:\n\n" << endl;
    for(vector<string>::iterator iter = contents.begin(); 
                                 iter !=contents.end(); iter++)
    {
           cout << *iter << endl;
    }
    return contents;  // return a copy of contents
}
```

You need to decide whether you want the caller to get a copy of the vector, or whether you want to allow them to get a *reference* to it. If you wanted to do so, your method would have to be one or both of

```
vector<string>& getCOntents();    // caller can get a read-write reference to contents
const vector<string>& getContents() const; // caller can get a read only reference to contents.
```

But beware, providing references to the internals of a class can be tricky to manage. At the very least, you must be sure that a `Album` object whose reference is taken by a caller lives at least as long as the reference.

Comment: Ah I see. This is where I am going wrong. I will add the return statement. Would it be wise to have two methods, one to return a copy and one to return a reference? How would those method differ? Thanks

Comment: Brilliant, you've just answered my question while I was typing it. Thanks for your help. :D

Comment: If you wish the Vector to hold certain objects from a class, say you have a `class book` and a `class store` and you wanted to create a vector of `book objects` in the `class store`, would you declare it like `vector<Book> bookList;`? would this accessor method work the same if you swapped string with Book?

Comment: @qwertyRocker yes, that would work. Your `Book` class would have to meet certain requirements depending on which vector operations you perform. If it is copyable, assignable and default constructible you should be pretty safe.